# Where to implement a stack class (to be used in a non recursive binary search function)

Tags: c++, binary, stack, queue, binary-search-tree

First of all, this sure is my homework but I will not be asking for code.

Inside a BST.h file, I implemented all the private members, functions and public functions. However, I am finding trouble where to implement a stack (a stack of pointers to `BSTNode`).

So would it be

```
#ifndef BINARYSEARCHTREE_H
#define BINARYSEARCHTREE_H

class BinarySearchTree
{
   struct Node {
      Node* left;
      Node* right;
      int val;
   };
};

#endif
```

so do I implement a stack class inside the `BinarySearchTree` class or outside the class in the same .h file?

The professor is not asking for 2 different .h files so I assume it should be either inside or outside. And if it is inside the binarysearchtree class, what about constructors for the stack class?

Comment: what your asking is a little confusing. you can have both your BST class and you stack seperated from each other but in the same .h file if they are logically connected. or you can nest the stack class inside your BST(not recomended).

Comment: Well, the standard library has a `<stack>` header and not a `<bsp_and_stack>` header!

Comment: @Koushik yeah you are right. Thanks for your help. I haven't made any separate classes (yes I did nested) inside one .h file and thus my uncertainty. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to implement the stack outside of the `BST` class. Typically, nested classes are used when the nested class is exclusively used with the parent class. For example, `Node` is nested because you wouldn't use a `Node` without the `BST`.

A stack isn't really related to the `BST` even though you're going to use it for the `BST`. If you design a good `stack`, that would allow you reuse it without needing to pull it out of `BST`.

It isn't incorrect to include multiple class declarations in a header file as long as they are small, and logically connected. But that comes down to style and project requirements.

Comment: Unrelated but I'm confused about why you would need a stack to implement a BST.

Comment: @AdamSchnitzer Thanks for your answer. So I assume it is OK to implement 2 separate classes inside a .h file?

Comment: @john You wouldn't. I imagine the assignment is to do a traversal with a stack.

Comment: @john for temporary non recursive traversals and deletion

Comment: @LeonardLie Yes, generally it is fine.

Comment: @AdamSchnitzer Thank you for your help! I will be coding now.